# Simple Neural Network Example with One Input and One Output in Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I am trying to learn how to use neural networks in MATLAB and I am starting with a simple example that uses four data points that I split into two row vectors. One of them is Input and the other is Temp. The input vector is a vector from 1 to 4.
Next I run some neural network coding I found from examples. Now I would like for the neural network to predict the outcome of a sample input vector which is a row vector [5 6].

```
clear all
clc
Input = [1,2,3,4];
Temp = [.25,.15,.1,.07];
Smpl = [5,6]
net = newff(minmax(Input),[20,1],{'logsig','purelin','trainlm'})
net.trainparam.epochs = 500;
net.trainparam.goal = 1e-25;
net.trainparam.lr = .01;
net = train(net,Input,Temp)
TempPr = net(Input)
error = TempPr - Temp
TempPrSmpl = net(Smpl)
```

The row vector, TempPr, generated by the neural network exactly matches with the target vector, Temp. However, it seems that I am unable to predict values properly. For example I try to predict temperature values for inputs 5 and 6 which I expect them to be less than .07.
But instead the matlab code is returning:

TempPrSmpl =

```
0.3560    0.3560
```

Two questions:
Why is the value being returned from MATLAB greater than .07?
Why are there not two different values being returned from MATLAB (one for 5 and one for 6)?

Comment: As far as I can tell you have 4 samples for training, and 20 neurons. So you have much more parameters than training samples. In such a scenario you cannot expect to generalize well.

Comment: ok thanks! I will add some more samples!